# Mysql group by in a CSV field

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, group-by

What's the best way to perform a group by statement in a csv-like column using SQL (mySQL)?

```
Table Products Color
+-------------+--------------+
| Product Id  | Color        |
+-------------+--------------+
| 120         | Red, Blue    |
| 121         | Green, Black | 
| 122         | Red, Black   | 
+-------------+--------------+
```

From the table above I need to count how many times a color appears and return something like this:

```
+-------------+-------+
| Color       | Count |
+-------------+-------+
| Red         | 2     |
| Blue        | 1     | 
| Green       | 1     | 
| Black       | 2     | 
+-------------+-------+
```

Is possible to do this without normalize the database?

Comment: The *best* way is to have an association table that has one item per product and color.  Storing data in a proper format for databases greatly simplifies database queries.  Do you have a table that lists all the colors?

Comment: No, i don't have! But i can create one. Did you suggesting query from this new table (with only colors) using REGEXP? Ps: I know the best way is use 1N approach but I'm working with web-services and some requests returns in CSV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change your table structure, but you can create a table that lists all the colors, you could use this query:

```
SELECT Colors.Color, Count(*)
FROM
  Products INNER JOIN Colors
  ON FIND_IN_SET(Colors.Color, REPLACE(Products.Color, ' ', ''))>0
GROUP BY
  Colors.Color
```

See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff071/1). Please notice that it can't be optimized because it can't make use on an index.

Comment: Nice, ty! Some of requests can handle with thousands of rows, did you think the index constraint will cause a huge slow down in queries?